# User field imported with Feeds but not showing in user edit page?

Tags: 7, feeds

I'm using Feeds Importer to create users from a csv file, in my Drupal 7 site.

It works perfectly, except one case. I added some custom fields to user profile and I can set all them with my importer, except one (a simple text field, let's say 'foo').

The value for 'foo' is correctly imported: if I open the 'View' page for a user profile I can see it, listed as supposed. In the 'Edit' page of the user profile, however, the value of the field is showed empty. If I modify the value in this edit page and save, the value is stored AND showed in the edit page.

I tried even to create another custom field similar to 'foo' and it works perfectly in any case. (I can't delete foo and recreate it for it contains several data)

How could this be debugged? I checked the csv, the importer, even the database (in the table field_data_field_foo the value is stored correctly), and all seems fine. No error in drupal log, neither in importer log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't delete foo and recreate it for it contains several data

Here is how I would try to fix this:

1. Backup your entire Drupal Database.
2. With phpmyadmin or some other database manager/viewer, find the field_foo table and extract the table as a CSV file.
3. In Drupal, go to user manage fields and Delete field foo
4. Flush the cache (not necessary, but eh, just in case)
5. Add a new field, foo
6. Edit user 1 and put something for field foo. (This is just so we get the table structure on step 7)
7. Find field_foo in DB and extract.
8. Open Original field foo .csv in excel and highlight all data and copy.
9. Open new field foo .csv and paste data and save
10. Import new field foo .csv to DB.
11. Flush/Clear the Cache
12. Try importing with feeds again and see what happens.

Comment: Not a bad idea, but the website is up and running. I can't risk to mess it up like this... It would be useful to know if the db structure of a new field goes beyond the table field_foo. Do you know something about this?

Comment: @SashaGrievus make a copy of your live site and test on the copy dev site. If you confirm that it works, then do the same on live site. You can put live site in maintenance mode for a few mins to do this.

Comment: Fair enough! :) I'll try to make it work in Acquia and see what happens. Thank you very much.

Comment: can this process will work in D8?

Comment: @ManmeetKhurana yes :)

Comment: I have field with plain text field type and created the new field with type number and inserted the record into the new field type table 
Record is showing properly but I have to perform sorting according to the new field  and its showing result according to the plain text not the number.
Ex :10 is showing first and 2 is later