# Sorting not working in the view SORT CRITERIA

Tags: views, 8, nodes

In my view want to sort the result according to the **work rank**  field value and in content value are in numeric number . its not showing result according to ascending order . its showing random .

How can sort the result according to the work rank field value in asc order?

[image]

Comment: Is it definitely “random”? As in different every time you refresh the page?

Comment: no , its fix but position is not according to the field value

Comment: work rank field type is text(plain) . can this be the issue ?if Yes How can I change the field type value to number

Comment: Yeah I was going to say - a text field is sorted alphanumerically, not numerically. 10 comes before 2 and all that. You can't just change a field type, you'll have to write a migration in an update hook

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/208946/how-do-i-change-a-field-type

this link will work for me ?

Comment: Yeah that's the right idea

Comment: I have changed the content type from  plain text to number and move content to new field but still its showing the same result as old one ?what i  miss here ?